# Airflow trigger_dag not working from command line

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the following `airflow` setup (version `v1.10.0`).

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Google Cloud Datalab',
    'email': [],
    'start_date': datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-07-04T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
    'end_date': None,
    'depends_on_past': False,
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='my_dag', schedule_interval='00 23 * * *', catchup=False, default_args=default_args)
```

The dag has been turned ON in the airflow UI. `airflow scheduler` is running too (`ps -ef | grep "airflow scheduler"` gives multiple hits).

I am trying to run this dag for a specific date in the past (2 days ago) using command line as

```
nohup airflow trigger_dag -e 2019-08-27 my_dag &
```

The command just exits after a few seconds. `nohup.out` shows the following in the end.

```
[2019-08-29 22:16:06,144] {cli.py:237} INFO - Created <DagRun my_dag @ 2019-08-27 00:00:00+00:00: manual__2019-08-27T00:00:00+00:00, externally triggered: True>
```

This is a fresh airflow instance and there have been no previous runs of the dag. How can I get it to run for the specific date?

Comment: trigger_dag has done it's job and created the DAG Run. Can you check Airflow Webserver and see if your DAG is running or not?

Comment: There must have been some issues that I overlooked. When the instance was rebuilt, things ran just fine. Thanks for responding. I'll close this one.